# How to display count of products in search Brand on search engine in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Want to show a count of Models in front of Brand Name like :

> 1. Nokia (10)
> 2. Phone (20)

I have use a `foreach` tobind a Brand Name Data. Below is a code of foreach

```
 @foreach (var item in this.Model.CompanyList)
 {
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbrand" id="chkbrand" value="@item.Brand"/>
    @item.Brand <span class="badge badge-info">4</span></a>
    </li>
 }
```

I have done a code in Model `public static int Count` which I want to call from `<span class="badge badge-info">4</span>` and replace a count with 4 with the result. Below is the static code

```
public static int Count(string Company)
{
  int count = 0;
  using (var db = new Entities())
  {
     count = (from o in db.Models
               where o.Brand == Company
               from t in o.Name
               select t).Count();
            }
         return count;            
  }
```

How can I call the `Modeal Public static` function in `foreach`?

Comment: @(MyClass.Count(item.Name))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call your method from your Razor view :

```
<span class="badge badge-info">@YourClass.Count(item.Name)</span></a>
```

Comment: It is a problem in your Count() method. If you are now able to call this method from your view, mark this question as resolved and ask another question related to your DB call explaining your model and your problem.

Comment: I have fixed it with malefaction my Class.Count